# Set variable to itself plus another variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, increment

I made a more complex (albeit only slightly) program in my CS class that ran some calculation and discounts according to some rules. It was written in Java, and read and output to a file. I am trying to redo it in JavaScript with a loop taking in input and applying calculations afterwards. I would call both functions after the second while loop closes.

My problem is that priceCount increments by price perfectly, while qty seems to just spit out somewhat random numbers (they're all multiples of inputs, however) with a leading 0. What's going on here? It's the exact same logic as the priceCount, but simply isn't working. I tried moving variables around, thinking it's a scope issue, but nothing worked.

I hope I'm not asking a question that has been answered many times. I tried searching extensively, but that is a skill in itself, and it is difficult for me to phrase my question into keywords. Any and all input will be greatly appreciated.

```
    function discountCalc (price, amount) {

  var discount;

  if (amount <= 30){
    discount = oldPrice * 0.05;
  }
  else if (amount >= 30 && amount <= 50){
    discount = oldPrice * 0.1;
  }
  else if (amount >= 51 && amount <= 75){
    discount = oldPrice * 0.25;
  }
  else {
  discount = oldPrice * 0.4;
  }
return discount;
}

function adjust(newPrice, amount){

  var adjust;

  if (newPrice < 500){
    adjust = -20;
  }
  else if (newPrice >= 500 && amount < 50){
    adjust = newPrice * 0.05;
  }
  else{
    adjust = 0;
  }
  return adjust;
}

var answer = "new", price, amount, customer = 1;

while (answer !== "quit" && answer !== "Quit" && answer !== "q" && answer !== "Q") {

console.log("invoice # 000" + customer);

if (answer == "new" || answer == "New") {

customer = customer + 1;

    var another = "yes";

var priceCount = 0;
var qty = 0;

    while (another == "yes" || another == "Yes" || another == "y" || another == "Y"){

  price = prompt("price?");
  amount = prompt("amount?");
  qty = qty + amount;
  priceCount = priceCount + (price * amount);
  console.log("Price: " + price + " Amount: " + amount);
  another = prompt("type yes for another, any key to stop");

}

console.log("Total price is: " + priceCount);
console.log("Total items: " + qty);

priceCount = 0;
qty = 0;

}

answer = prompt("new or quit?");
}

console.log("thanks");
```

Comment: Inputs from `prompt` are strings. You need to convert them to a number first before doing something like `qty = qty + amount`

Comment: I don't actually see you ever calling the `discountCalc` or `adjust` functions.  Where/how did you intend to include them?

Comment: Small thing about your if conditions: you don't need to check the lower boundary each time. If the program's control flow reaches the second condtion in the `discountCalc` function, `amount` is definitely greater than 30 and so on.

Comment: discountCalc will be called at the end of each price amount pair, adjust will be called before a new invoice is made after the second while loop. I see what you're saying about the lower boundary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompt returns a string, so you should convert it to a number.
You can use parseInt(), parseFloat(), or Number().
parseInt() returns an integer value, and parseFloat() returns a float.
Number() can return both, but if the prompt returns string that doesn't evaluate to numbers, it returns NaN. It can be useful to check if the user is giving invalid data.

So replace

```
qty = qty + amount
```

to

```
qty = qty + Number(amount) //or parseInt(amount), parseFloat(amount)
```

if you have other areas adding amount to a number, you can do the same.